# Excel to show custom date format with milliseconds

Tags: excel, formatting, format

I have dates in CSV like this

```
  2015-08-04 10:09:25.940
```

Default Excel representation of this value is

```
09:25.9
```

Could you please provide exact steps to force Excel to show something sane?

Comment: What would something sane be? Do you want it to say `10:09:26` or `10:09:25.94`? What do you mean by "sane"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right Clic: Format Cell :
Custom: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"

Comment: Thanks, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000 perfectly works for me, I was adding .###